# Проверить каждый Div на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня на странице имеется пару десятков дивов с одним и тем же классом (пусть это будет '.test'). Можно ли проверить все дивы на соответствие определенному условию?Если быть точнее, мне надо узнать определенный атрибут у каждого элемента .test, сравнить, есть ли в localStorage запись с таким же именем, как и атрибут у .test, и если эта запись имеется, то сделать какое то действие с определенным элементом .test). Надо всё это сделать не по клику на элемент (что было бы в 1000 раз легче, я думаю), а именно по document.ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый элемент выборки проверяется с помощью `.each()`:

```
  $(function() {
    $('.test').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).attr("someAttribute") == "someValue" ) {
          //do something
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает :)

Answer (score 2):

или на чистом JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function (div) {
        if (div.getAttribute("someAttribute") === "someValue") {
            //do something
        };
    })
});
```